# fundamental theorem of linear maps (consideration)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

i've saw on the linear algebra done right the theorem of linear maps

$$ \dim V = \dim (\text{null} T)+\dim(\text{range} T) $$

and i was asking myself if this theorem is legit also without dim like so
$$V = \text{null} T+\text{range}T $$

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A counterexample: let $T : \mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}^2$ be the linear map whose matrix with respect to the standard basis is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then you can check that $\text{null}(T) = \text{range}(T) = \text{span}((0, 1))$. Consequently,
$$
\text{null}(T) + \text{range}(T) = \text{span}((0, 1)) \neq \mathbf{R}^2.
$$
However, the result is true if $T$ is diagonalizable.